# Random order set to certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-order-by

Is there a way to do a random order on a listing of events and have it stay that way only for the day?  There is paging involved so caching isn't really a good option.

I know I can do random ordering by `NEWID()`, but that would show a different order on page 100 if it was never cached and contain the same items on page 1.  If it was by date, then it will show the ordering, no matter the page cache, and reset the next day.

```
    WITH PagedResults AS 
        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Name' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ep.Name DESC, ev.Id ASC)
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ev.Id ASC) END  AS [Row],
            CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Name' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ep.Name ASC, ev.Id DESC)
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ev.Id DESC)
            END  AS [RowReverse],
                ev.Id,
                ep.Name,
    )
        SELECT 
                [Row] + RowReverse - 1 AS Total, 
                [Row],
                [RowReverse],
                Id, 
                Name,
        FROM PagedResults
        WHERE [Row] BETWEEN (((@Page - 1) * @PageSize) + 1) AND (@Page * @PageSize)
        ORDER BY [Row], [RowReverse] DESC
```

Comment: You have to generate your random order and then temporarily store it somewhere. I guess you could convert your random order to seconds and add it to the current datetime as a form of caching.

Comment: you could generate some sort of computed hash column that would consist of fixed date portion and randomised suffix. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If you use `RAND()` for your random ordering, you can use the date as a seed. Then the sequence of random numbers will be the same for the day. Might not be very efficient though.

Comment: What do you propose to happen if someone inserts or deletes a row? By the way, I suggest you look into [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), it is far more efficient than Rowset Pagination

Comment: Is it possible to add an extra column to the table?

Comment: May I know the reason behind this requirement? Just to understand it accurately.

Comment: The reason is users post events on our site and we are showing by name ordering, however its not fair to everyone to say have there event last within a certain grouping so we want to order it differently at the end of our prior ordering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following I will use the table `sortme` defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE sortme
             (id integer
                 IDENTITY (1, 1),
              PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Using `ORDER BY rand(<seed>)` with `<seed>` derived from the current day might be the first approach that comes into mind.

```
DECLARE @today datetime = '2021-01-01 01:01:01';

SELECT *
       FROM sortme
       ORDER BY rand(convert(integer,
                             convert(varchar(8),
                                     @today,
                                     112)));
```

`rand()` guarantees that the value generated is the same, if the `<seed>` is the same. So we got this one point checked. Sort of... because the value will also be the same for every row. So using `rand(<seed>)` for a fixed `<seed>` will effectively do nothing.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ebccedd7aac66f7c7ec39e08d5f02821)

We can try to overcome this by binding the random value to a key of the result. The random value will be stable for day and key, i.e. the row the key identifies, for a day.

```
    DECLARE @today datetime = '2021-01-01 01:01:01';
    SELECT *
           FROM sortme
           ORDER BY rand(id * 100000000
                         + 
                         convert(integer,
                                 convert(varchar(8),
                                         @today,
                                         112)));
```

But unfortunately, every (simple) formula to combine the key and the day I came up with did produce random values close enough for every day, so that the order ways the same every day. It didn't scatter well.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=af50bbfa6de3605418fc0343b498d9e3)

Now if we think about it, we want a function that scatters even monotonically increasing values well. And that is the domain of hash functions.

So we can use `hashbytes()`.

```
DECLARE @today datetime = '2021-01-01 01:01:01';

SELECT *
       FROM sortme
       ORDER BY hashbytes('SHA2_512',
                          concat(convert(varchar(8),
                                         @today,
                                         112),
                                 id));
```

The hash will be stable throughout the day and the key for a row as it depends only on these values. And the fact that (certain) hash functions scatter well, makes the result "look random".

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=956ed0a0177e604adcf7e9afc497faa7)

Deleting from or inserting into the table will of course result in rows appear or disappear somewhere in between other "old" or remaining rows. But if the key we use is stable, say like an auto increment that doesn't fill gaps, the order of the "old" or remaining rows among themselves will be stable throughout the day anyway.

Of course, be aware that this isn't random in terms of being unpredictable!

But I assume that its purpose is just about improving the user experience, presenting a result that "feels" random each day to make the content more interesting and exciting. It should be good enough for that.

Comment: FYI, `rand(convert(integer, convert(varchar(8), @today, 112)))` in SQL Server returns the same number for each row in your first query. The seed is the same for each row, the `RAND` result is the same for each row.

Comment: I was going to propose something similar but using `BINARY_CHECKSUM`. I guess it's a bit less demanding resource-wise both for calculating the value and doing the sorting afterwards as it's just an integer that's being returned. The downside might be that it has a higher chance of collisions but I did a test with id ranging from 1 to 5M and had no doubles. `ORDER BY BINARY_CHECKSUM(Convert(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), id)`

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: Thanks! I must have confused myself somewhere along the way... I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @deroby: That's probably a good suggestion, I'd love to edit that in. But when I test it, the order doesn't look too random to me. A large portion seems to be just sorted by the (auto increment) key and several days look the same: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=723707ac68eee7bdc869e14a84429cd4 Have I misunderstood your suggestion and made a mistake?

Comment: @stickybit Nope, you did it perfectly but it seems I (vastly) over-estimated the power of `BINARY_CHECKSUM()`. When you turn around the `date` and `id` parameters it's slightly better but still not good enough IMHO. That should teach me for not trying things out first =P Anyway, to mitigate I tried adding a 'salt' value first -- just a string -- and if it's long enough it makes it less bad, but still not great. Better stick to the hashes I guess. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8a1d50b2079734343f5979cc954def1c

Comment: this is a great idea, however If anything gets updated/deleted/inserted , the order will be different after that transaction

Comment: @eshirvana: Yes, a new record might appear somewhere in between or there might be a gap when a record is deleted. But I already addressed that in the answer.

Comment: This actually works pretty well.  Going to give it a try for now.